# boolean in sharedPreferences not always save correcly

Tags: android, boolean, android-sharedpreferences

I have a strange issue. In One activity I have list with checkbox fields, the state of check box depends of shared prefrence, but it's work sometimes and sometimes not(It means sometimes when I checked the checkbox then back to the previous activity, and return into my checkBox activity the sharedPrefrences value is not changed). I thought it's happend because I'm change the activity too quick so i put saving logic in thread but got the same problem.

Here is some code that I've tried:

```
    public final static String PREFERENCES_NAME = "USER_PREFERENCES";
       public final static String PLAY_REQUIRED = "PLAY_REQUIRED";
          sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        recordCheckBox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.recordRequiredCheckBox);
        recordCheckBox.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PLAY_REQUIRED,true));
        findViewById(R.id.playRequiredItem).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                if(recordCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    recordCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                    preferencesEditor.putBoolean(PLAY_REQUIRED, false).apply();
                    preferencesEditor.commit();
                    Log.i("kamil","AfterSetFalseCheckBox :: "+ sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PLAY_REQUIRED,true));
                }
                else {
                    recordCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                    preferencesEditor.putBoolean(PLAY_REQUIRED, true).apply();
                    preferencesEditor.commit();
                    Log.i("kamil","AfterSetTrueCheckBox :: "+ sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PLAY_REQUIRED,true));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Remove .apply() . apply() is used for asynchronous saving in SP.

Comment: Remove AsyncTask and used direct  preferencesEditor.putBoolean(PLAY_REQUIRED, check).apply();
                preferencesEditor.commit();

Comment: try too remove `getApplicationContext().` from `sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: removing async task is trying to solve the issue, so it wont help. CoDfather the 'getApplicationContext()' was also try to solve the issue

Comment: @Expiredmind Could you edit your post with the current code?

Comment: @Expiredmind Where are you assigning to `sharedPreferences`? Try doing it in `onCreate`

Comment: Interesting. I have something similar as well. Have you tried to replace `putBoolean(PLAY_REQUIRED, true)` (or `false`) with `putInt(PLAY_REQUIRED, 1)` (or `0`) and, respectively, `getBoolean(PLAY_REQUIRED, true)` with `getInt(PLAY_REQUIRED, 1) == 1`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happened because whenever you put the value in sharedpreference than value inserted in one sharedprefrences, and when you get the value from sharedpreference is getting from another sharedpreference. So, I suggest you create proper helper class for sharedpreference and use it whenever you want.

Here is the example of that:

```
 public class PreferenceHelper {

    public static SharedPreferences AppPreference;

    // Preference name for app.
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCE_NAME = "app_preference_name";

     /**
     * Set boolean value to shared-preference.
     *
     * @param key   Key for store boolean value to shared-preference.
     * @param value Boolean value to be stored in shared-preference for given key.
     */
    public static void putBoolean(Context context,String key, boolean value) {
        AppPreference = context
                .getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = AppPreference.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Get boolean value from shared-preference.
     *
     * @param key          Key for getting boolean value from shared-preference.
     * @param defaultValue Default boolean value that is returned if given key is not found in
     *                     preference.
     * @return string      Boolean value from shared-preference for given key.
     */
    public static boolean getBoolean(Context context,String key, boolean defaultValue) {
        AppPreference = context
                .getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean string = AppPreference.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
        return string;
    }
}
```

and use it like:

To set value:

```
PreferenceHelper.putBoolean(getApplicationContext(),"key",value);
```

To get value:

```
Boolean boolean = PreferenceHelper.getBoolean(getApplicationContext(),"key",defalut-value);
```

Comment: is that mean if we have multiple activities so the sharedpreference will be different for each activities instead of just one?

Answer (score -1):

You can used below method for set and get boolean value.

**/*For Set Boolean Value in Preference*/**

```
public void setBooleanValue(String key, boolean value, Context context) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

**/*For Get Boolean Value in Preference*/**

```
public boolean getBooleanValue(String key, Context context) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean value = preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: It is not his problem try to understand the question. @Expiredmind did it also.